# how to plug out numbers saved as string like ["3","4","5"] in php

Tags: php

how do i plug out the numbers in the string in php and store it in different variables

```
$var = '["3","4","5"]';
```

Expected Result:

```
$var1=3;
$var2=4;
$var3=5;
```

Comment: That's an array, not a string. Explain why you think you'd need this.

Comment: no i saved it as a string! if i echo  out gettype it prints the $var type as "string"  i just need to plug out those numbers from that string and save it in each variables

Comment: So, what you really have is JSON then?

Comment: @mario yes i saved it in db and getting that json string back

Comment: @mario do you know how to plug out this json string please could you tell me how

Comment: PD of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29308898) / [Using braces with dynamic variable names in PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/9257505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are many ways to do it with loop, list, extract and others etc. You can try with PHP [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to make variables out of your array values.

```
<?php
$var=["3","4","5"];
// Listing all the variables
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $var;
echo "var1 is $var1, var2 is $var2 and var3 is $var3. \n";
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/8sDdI

with `extract()` slightly modify your array

```
<?php
$array = array("var1" => "3","var2" => "4", "var3" => "5");
extract($array);
echo "\$var1 = $var1; \$var2 = $var2; \$var3 = $var3";
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/hG3PX

Comment: thank you for your answers! i tried those but dint work! i have a json string and trying to plug out those string values individually

Comment: i'm selecting your answer only change was i had a json string value i changed it to array using json_decode($var) then i used your "list" solution and it worked! thank you!

Comment: @faiz glad it helps you somehow mate. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i = 1;
$var=array("3","4","5");
foreach($var as $value){
    ${'var'.$i} = $value;
    $i++;
    }
```

It will work perfectly for any case. Let me know if you need any other help in this regard.

Comment: This will works even when you have many values in the array and will create as many variables as values.

Comment: let me know if you need any other help in this regard. And if you find the answer useful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark(grey colored) on the left of the answer. And also upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the type :

```php
$var=["3","4","5"];
$var1 = (int)$var[0];
$var2 = (int)$var[1];
$var3 = (int)$var[2];
```